# PHP Function not return array or int

Tags: php, mysql, function, return, categories

I have this function, but don't "return" any data;

```
function getCategoryParent($db,$id,$count = 12){
$parentID=0;
$inner = "";
for ($i=2; $i<=$count; $i++){
    $inner .=' INNER JOIN services_categories as x'.$i.' ON x'.$i.'.sc_id=x'.($i-1).'.sc_top_id ';
}
$sql='SELECT x'.$count.'.* FROM services_categories as x1 ' .$inner. ' WHERE x1.sc_id="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
$query=$db->query($sql,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($query->rowCount()){
    foreach ($query as $key) {
        $parentID=$key["sc_id"];
        return $parentID;

    }
}else{
    getCategoryParent($db,$id,$count-1);
} }
```

I want return `sc_id` or all query data. it's working with echo

Comment: From where are you calling this function ? "getCategoryParent"

Comment: service single page

 $pid = getCategoryParent($db,$id);
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM services_categories WHERE sc_id='$pid'",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Have you tried putting "return getCategoryParent($db,$id,$count-1); " in the else case ?

Comment: Thank @Nandan it's woking

Comment: you're doing recursion, but never bother returning the value returned by the recursive call...

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: @ErenÖzkul you have   logic error in your code